# intersection of two curves in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to find the two intersection points of `pdf` function of normal distribution.

I have calculated all the point (x,y) for the curves by `iy = pdf('normal', ix, mu, sd)` and plotted them on the screen which has two intersection points.
I have tried `fzero` function but it does not work the means and standard deviations are different for both curves so the length of the arrays are different.
I tried simplest logic two for loops but it did not work either.

The **brute force approach did not work for me** because of the precision in matlab it does not consider 24.000 and 24.001 for example and the resulting values from the gaussian has 15 integers after decimal point which made it impossible for matlab to check for equality.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Trying to improve the answer as this is an accepted answer(Full credit to **Eitan T** who has explained beautifully in this **[related answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384516/show-the-intersection-of-two-curves)** about intersection of curves)

You'll have to find the point of intersection (px, py) manually:

```
idx = find(y1 - y2 < eps, 1); %// Index of coordinate in array
px = x(idx);
py = y1(idx);
```

Remember that we're comparing two numbers in floating point representation, so instead of `y1 == y2` we must set a tolerance. I've chosen it as eps, but it's up to you to decide.

To draw a circle around this point, you can compute its points and then plot them, but a better approach would be to plot one point with a blown-up circle marker (credit to Jonas for this suggestion):

```
plot(px, py, 'ro', 'MarkerSize', 18)
```

This way the dimensions of the circle are not affected by the axes and the aspect ratio of the plot.

Answer (score 6):

Only jump to numerical methods if analysis fails. Finding the intersection points of two normal distributions is a fairly simple algebra problem, which I am too lazy now to do properly, but Matlab can do it for me:

```
>> syms x sig1 sig2 mu1 mu2;
>> solve(1/sig1/sqrt(2*pi) * exp(-1/2*((x-mu1)/sig1)^2) == ...
         1/sig2/sqrt(2*pi) * exp(-1/2*((x-mu2)/sig2)^2), x)

ans =

 +(mu2*sig1^2 - mu1*sig2^2 + sig1*sig2*(2*sig2^2*log(sig2/sig1) - 2*sig1^2*log(sig2/sig1) - 2*mu1*mu2 + mu1^2 + mu2^2)^(1/2))/(sig1^2 - sig2^2)
 -(mu1*sig2^2 - mu2*sig1^2 + sig1*sig2*(2*sig2^2*log(sig2/sig1) - 2*sig1^2*log(sig2/sig1) - 2*mu1*mu2 + mu1^2 + mu2^2)^(1/2))/(sig1^2 - sig2^2)
```

where `sig1, sig2` are the first and second standard deviation, and `mu1, mu2` are the first and second mean, respectively.

Comment: Exactly! The simplest way is usually NOT brute force :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer the problem i face with this is that x's had different rages so different number of elements inside whih caused different dimensions in matrixes so the solve method give an error. As ı had calculated all the x and y points for both curves ı wrote 2 for loops and see that actually matlab precision failed such as 24.0000 and 24.0001 is not considered as same so I putted a tolerance value and solved my problem. Thank your for your reply.

Comment: @BurakUzun: You didn't understand what I was explaining. You should solve the problem *analytically*, so you don't have to compute "all" points for *x* and *y* for both pdf's. It's something like: how would you compute where the line `y=x` and `y=2x` intersect? I say: that's easy: at `x==y==0`. You say: I'll just generate a few dozen points for each line, and loop through them to see which ones have the smallest difference. and you find `x=0.01` and `y=-0.04` for the intersection. It's just silly, and most of all, *incorrect*. But OK, suit yourself.

Comment: +1 for showing an alternative to brute force and for showing how to do it in general.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Yes you are right and thank you for your attention but as i plot the distributions i need to calculate those point but your answer is more general than that.

Comment: @BurakUzun: Why then not calculate the intersection points, and plot those in separately? It sure sounds a lot easier...

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer a numerical approach to an analytic one, you can use `fzero` and the `normpdf` function.

`x_intersect = fzero(@(x) normpdf(x, mu1, std1) - normpdf(x, mu2, std2), x0);`

Since the normal distribution is well behaved, and any two distributions must intersect, any initial guess `x0` should work.