# Plotting intersections on line graphs in R

Tags: r, graph, plot, intersection

I want to use R to plot two data series with the same x-values (e.g. dates). I want the two lines on the same graph, but the segments where the one is larger than the other should be in another colour. So as an example:

```
x<-c(-5:5)
y1<-x^2-x-10
y2<-(x^3)-(x^2)-(10*x)+2
plot(x,y1,col="blue", ylim=c(-100,100), type="l")
par(new=T)
plot(x,y2,col="green", ylim=c(-100,100), type="l")
```

with the sections where y2 is larger than y1 to be red. Thus the green line would be red more or less where -3 < x < 1 and then again when x > 3 (I tried to post the figure but my reputation isn't high enough). I want to develop a bit of code that would allow me to do this for any set of data, for example in a matrix something like:

```
xy<-as.matrix(cbind(x,y1,y2))
```

I have a suspicion that it could be done using `for` and `if` loops, but I'd prefer a more elegant solution. If I could do something like this: [Show the intersection of two curves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384516/show-the-intersection-of-two-curves) as well, that would be great!

Thanks so much in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very basic solution achieved by  creating a couple new variables, with `NA` values to suppress plotting in the undesired regions:

```
y2high <- y2
y2high[y2high < y1] <- NA
y2low <- y2
y2low[y2low > y1] <- NA

plot(x,y1,type='l', col='blue')
lines(x,y2high,col='red')
lines(x,y2low,col='green')
```