# Distance measurement in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have tried the code from the link [Ear Image Processing - Finding the point of intersection of line and curve in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22009416/ear-image-processing-finding-the-point-of-intersection-of-line-and-curve-in-ma) 
but seem to get an error as dist2s is undefined on matlab R2013a.Can anyone help me out

Comment: You should try to share some code and examples.

Comment: The `dist2s` function is defined in that answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you need to create the function (isn't defined by MatLab itself). Try saving this code in a file called **dist2s.m** and then setting the folder where it's located like current folder:

```
function out = dist2s(pt1,pt2)

out = NaN(size(pt1,1),size(pt2,1));
for m = 1:size(pt1,1)
    for n = 1:size(pt2,1)
        if(m~=n)
            out(m,n) = sqrt( (pt1(m,1)-pt2(n,1)).^2 + (pt1(m,2)-pt2(n,2)).^2 );
        end
    end
end
return;
```

The code is provided in the same answer you refer to.

Comment: Now I got it.I am using this technique to identify different ears.I am going to sore the identities in MS Access database and link it to matlab.So when i capture an image of the ear it will do edge detection and calculate the distance and try to match with the database .Can you give me any advice on this.