# cordinate of intersection pixel of 2 line segments in a chess-board

Tags: matlab, intersection, hough-transform, canny-operator

I'm working on a project that
have to find the coordinate of intersection point of two line segments
these line segments are the Perpendicular lines of a chessboard image.
i find the line segments with Hough transform after using canny edje detection.
I find the start and end point of each line![enter image description here][1]
but I don' know how can I find the coordinate of the intersection of these lines.

time is running out.
any one who could, please help me.
I'm working with matlab
all I have are the results of the code below.
there's my code:

> im = imread('IMG_2917.jpg');
>
> Im = rgb2gray(im);
>
> q = max(min(Im));
>
> I = Im <= q;
>
> A = ceil(min(size(I))/2);
>
> B = ceil(max(size(I)));
>
> figure
>
> sigma=1;
>
> BW = edge(I, 'canny', [], sigma);
>
> [H,T,R] = hough(BW);
>
> P = houghpeaks(H,8,'threshold',ceil(0.25*max(H(:))));
>
> x = T(P(:,2));
>
> y = R(P(:,1));
>
> Q(:,1) = R(P(:,1));
>
> Q(:,2) = T(P(:,2))
>
> lines = houghlines(BW,T,R,P,'FillGap',B,'MinLength',A);
>
> imshow(BW)
>
> hold on
>
> max_len = 0;
>
> for k = 1:length(lines)
>
> xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
>
> plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');
>
> plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','yellow');
>
> plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');
>
> disp(['line #' num2str(k) ':(' num2str(xy(1,1)) ',' num2str(xy(1,2)) ')' ';' ...
>
> '(' num2str(xy(2,1)) ',' num2str(xy(2,2)) ')']);
>
> len = norm(lines(k).point1 - lines(k).point2);
>
> if (len > max_len)
>
> max_len = len;
>
> xy_long = xy;
>
> end
>
> end
>
> plot(xy_long(:,1),xy_long(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','blue');

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection  Have you tried googling for line intersection?

Comment: also. are you using a library for this? Like opencv? Please include more information in your questioon and what language you're using

Comment: @ EJEHardenberg could you please explain how this code could work for me.

Comment: aah, matlab, looks to me like you have the points stored in your array already so it should be easy enough to use the code in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16384654/1808164 to find the intersection using said points.