# Matlab intersection graph with line

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, line, intersection

I have a graph, in which I plotted a horizontal line:

```
plot(alphaVals,plotDataAlpha,...
[0 max(alphaVals,[Eper,Eper],'k-')
```

Where alphaVals is linspace(0,180) (so 1x100 double) and plotDataAlpha is a function which gives a 7x100 double. Eper is the variable for the horizontal line which I set on 50.

All this results in the following figure:
[image: Matlab output figure].

Now I want to get all the coordinatates of the intersection of each of the Vfiber lines with the Eper line set on 50. So the intersection of each colored line with the black line. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show the intersection of two curves](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384516/show-the-intersection-of-two-curves)

Comment: I tried that but it is not quite working, espacially not because there are 5 lines intersecting so I should get 10 points, I only get one, which is not even on an intersection point. I looked at other posts but I still can't figure it out.

Comment: Of course it's not quite working, you need to put some thought into understanding it and not just copy+paste the code. Each of the rows in the return of `plotDataAlpha` corresponds to your data set, so you probably want to operate on each row individually. The `find` call in the linked duplicate only returns the *first* index, [look at the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) and see what you could change to fix this.