# Point of Intersection in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, intersection

How can I

- plot the point intersection of two curves in MATLAB?
- And obtain that point in its mathematical form programmatically?

For simplicity I have taken two very basic curves :

- y=x
- y= cos(x)

I am able to plot the curves but cannot obtain the intersection point. See the screenshot:

[image]

I have tried the solutions proposed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384516/show-the-intersection-of-two-curves#) question but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Try `idx = find((y2-y1)==min(abs(y2-y1)),1)`. This doesn't imply that your functions truely cross as explained by Arief, but will find where they are closest to crossing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regards User. If I may ask, your objective is to obtain the **exact point** that *intersect* those two functions, or the **nearest point** to the *intersection* point? (the latter using approximation)

Here is an idea :

**1)**  If your discretization : `x=0:0.05:2;` do contain the *intersection* point, you can use the `intersect` function in Matlab.

For example

```
intersect([1,2,3],[4,3,1])
```

will return a vector with two elements `1` and `3`, the *intersection* of those two vectors.

To find the intersection point is to find the point x such that y1(x)=y2(x). So apply

```
yin = intersect(y1,y2);
```

After this, since your `x` is sorted, you should check the value in `yin` that has the **same index** in both `y1` and `y2`.

The value that satisfy that condition is the intersection point in the y-axis.

**2)** If your `x` does not include the intersection point in x-axis, then use numerical methods. To find the roots of `y2-y1`. (or the points where g(x)=y2(x)-y1(x) = 0, since this is as same as y1(x)=y2(x))

You can try these first. Hope this will be useful. Thanks.