# Points of intersection in R

Tags: r, math, intersection, lines

This might be a stupid question...

I've two vectors containing Y coords
X is simply 1:8

I've added the lines to a plot area and would like to identify the point of intersection of the two lines.

Is there a default package to find this?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a [duplicate from 5 days ago?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982146/point-of-intersection-2-normal-curves/16982314#16982314)

Comment: @JackRyan I'd say `uniroot` is serious overkill for a couple lines :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intersection of two lines is found analytically by solving the two linear equations which define the lines.  I'll leave the math as an exercise to the OP.

If you want to use a very helpful and powerful package, you could read up on the package `spatstat` .  Once you've converted your lines into `psp` objects, use `spatstat:crossing.psp` to find intersections.